# How to upload a WAV file to S3 from the /tmp folder in AWS Lambda using Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've successfully created an AWS Lambda function to process some audio using sox and store the result to the /tmp folder.  I'd like to upload the result file to S3.  I've tried multiple ways but haven't got it to work.  Here is my function:

```
const lambdaAudio = require('lambda-audio')
const fs = require('fs')

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  lambdaAudio.sox('./input.mp3 -c 1 /tmp/output.wav')
    .then(response => {
        if (fs.existsSync('/tmp/output.wav')) {
              console.log('output.wav file exists.')  // This works!

              // UPLOAD TO S3 HERE  HOW???

        }            
    })
    .catch(errorResponse => {
      console.log('Error from the sox command:', errorResponse)
    })
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's my final working version incorporating dpwrussell's answer:

```
var lambdaAudio = require('lambda-audio')
var fs = require('fs')
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var accessKeyId =  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var secretAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  lambdaAudio.sox('./input.mp3 -c 1 /tmp/output.wav')
    .then(response => {
        if (fs.existsSync('/tmp/output.wav')) {
              console.log('output.wav file exists.')  

              uploadToS3();

        }            
    })
    .catch(errorResponse => {
      console.log('Error from the sox command:', errorResponse)
    })
}

function uploadToS3() {
  fs.readFile('/tmp/output.wav', function (err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.putObject({
      Bucket: 'my-bucket',
      Key: 'output.wav',
      Body: base64data
    },function (resp) {
      console.log('Done');
    });

  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the S3 API. The lamba function role will need permission to upload to this S3 bucket.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
fs.readFile('/tmp/output.wav', function (err, data) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Key: 'output.wav'
    Body: base64data
  },function (resp) {
    console.log('Done');
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried adding this to my code but I got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'putObject' of undefined".  See my update above for the code.

Comment: My typo, it's `s3.putObject`, not `s3.client.putObject`. corrected in answer.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  It works!  I posted the update under my original question above.